# Not able to pass date --rfc-3339=seconds command output to curl

Tags: shell, jenkins

I am trying to make a api call using curl command and trying to pass a shell output to one of the argument
Hence i have followed below but its throwing error . But when i hardcode the value it works fine . Can someone help me on this issue .

```
D_timedate=`date --rfc-3339=seconds`
curl --location URL --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{
                "component":"XXXXXX",
                "title":"*******",
                "description":"***********",
                "status":"success",
                "version":"XXXXXX",
                "release_time":"'${D_timedate}'"
                }'
```

**{"code":400,"message":"Rejection(BodyDeserializeError { cause: Error("EOF while parsing a string", line: 7, column: 42) })"}curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 33:
05:49:56-04:00"**
}

"release_time" expects string format input .

But when i pass the value instead of the variable , call is successful .

I want to know how i can pass the variable . How the variable/value can be converted to required field format . Same i am trying to execute under a jenkins stage